# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string error - last field selected causing the error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm receiving the error in the title of this post. The error is happening when the very last case statement is included in the query. If the last case statement is taken out, the script will run.

What might be the issue?

```
USE Reporting

DECLARE @QuarterBeginDate date = '07-01-2021'
DECLARE @QuarterEndDate date = '09-30-2021'

SELECT  GETDATE() AS RefreshDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RowID) RowID,
        ReportDate AS ReportDate,
        AssetName AS [Investment Name],
        BuildingName AS [Property Name],
        '3Q21' AS QTR,
        TenantName AS [Tenant Name],
        CASE
            WHEN LeaseSignedDate BETWEEN @QuarterBeginDate AND @QuarterEndDate 
                THEN LeaseType
            WHEN ReportLeaseEndDate BETWEEN @QuarterBeginDate AND @QuarterEndDate 
                THEN 'Vacate'
            ELSE 'N/A'
        END AS [Lease Type],
        SpaceLeaseArea AS [Sq Ft],
        CASE
            WHEN LeaseSignedDate BETWEEN @QuarterBeginDate AND @QuarterEndDate 
                THEN IncomeStartDate
            WHEN ReportLeaseEndDate BETWEEN @QuarterBeginDate AND @QuarterEndDate 
                THEN ReportLeaseEndDate
            ELSE 'N/A'
        END AS [Rent Start Date or Date Vacated],
        CASE
            WHEN LeaseSignedDate BETWEEN @QuarterBeginDate AND @QuarterEndDate 
                THEN IncomeEndDate
            WHEN ReportLeaseEndDate BETWEEN @QuarterBeginDate AND @QuarterEndDate 
                THEN 'N/A'
            ELSE 'N/A'
        END AS [Rent/Lease End Date]
FROM 
    dbo.LeaseData
WHERE
    (LeaseSignedDate BETWEEN @QuarterBeginDate AND @QuarterEndDate) 
    OR (ReportLeaseEndDate BETWEEN @QuarterBeginDate AND @QuarterEndDate)
```

Comment: Because your last case expression is returning multiple datatypes which you can't do. So for rows that would return 'N/A' it is trying to convert that to a datetime. Let your query return NULL and if you want to display N/A that would be something you handle in the presentation layer, not the database.

Comment: you either need to follow the advice above or cast your dates to a string - the error is because the case expression is following the data type order of precedence and trying to cast `'N/A'` as a date

Comment: See [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for an explanation of how the result data type is determined when data types are mixed in an expression, e.g. a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) _expression_. (There is no `case` _statement_ in T-SQL.)